# Create an automated PDF on form submission and provide a download buton in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf-generation, form-submit

On submission of a form, I want to add the details into a specified format pdf and enable the option to download the pdf. Link to the GitHub repo with the implemented form: https://github.com/muskankhedia/Invoice

Comment: What exactly is the question? Do you have code you wrote to share?

Comment: You can find the complete working of the code at https://github.com/muskankhedia/Invoice. It contains a form, I want to create a PDF of the form and avail a download option on its submission.

Comment: The code not found.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @OrAssayag My bad, the repo was private. Please find the code now in the same link.

Comment: @YashJoshi I have tried to create a form, and use html-pdf package to create a pdf, but that requires to replicate the form design in HTML in order to provide a design to the pdf and insert the submitted details. I have also tried all other resources available over the internet but couldn't find a reliable solution. I want to build a system to enable the user to submit multiple forms and anytime download the submitted form in form of pdf.